# Box library for Apex?

Tags: apex

Does anyone know of a library or package for calling out to Box via Apex?

I've seen [box-apex-sdk](https://github.com/Avinava/box-apex-sdk) which was built for the Box API's now-deprecated version 1.  It looks like it probably wouldn't be too hard to modify and update for version 2, but I wanted to check to avoid reinventing the wheel if there is already work on a library for version 2.

Looking for features such as:
 - From a Controller, query for a list of files to display in a VF page
 - Create a folder on Box
 - Upload a file to Box

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got a repo on [Github that uses v2](https://github.com/dhoechst/ApexBox). Please take a look. I'd love pull requests to improve it...

Comment: Looks awesome, I'll check it out!